# Absolute Value constraints in lpSolve in R

Tags: r, linear-programming, absolute-value, lpsolve

I would like to further constrain the system below with the following additional constraint, which makes use of the absolute value operator:

```
abs(x1)+abs(x2)+abs(x3) <= 10
```

Is there a feasible way to implement these additional absolute value constraints in R?

System of equations:

```
maximize: x1 + 9x2 + x3;

subject to:

x1 + 2x2 + 3x3 <= 9

3x1 + 2x2 + 2x3 <= 15
```

R Code:

```
require(lpSolve)
# objective function, constants, constraints
obj = c(1,9,1)
con = matrix(c(1,2,3,3,2,2), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
rel = c("<=", "<=")
rhs = c(9,15)
```

Solution:

```
my.lp = lp("max", obj, con, rel, rhs)
my.lp$objval
my.lp$solution
```

Obviously this is a simple example to illustrate the problem I pulled after searching online. It seems there is an approach in `lp_solve` itself, as evidenced [here](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/index.htm) in the `lp_solve` online help guide. However, I would prefer to keep the problem framed in R if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To model `|x|` in an LP, you typically create two new variables, `x^-` and `x^+`. Constrain them both to be nonnegative:

```
x^-, x^+ >= 0
```

Then each time you have `x` in your model, replace it with `x^+ - x^-`, and each time you have `|x|`, replace it with `x^+ + x^-`. Note that this only works if you're using a simplex-based LP solver rather than an interior-point method. lp_solve uses simplex.

The reason why this works is: Suppose `x = 10` in the optimal solution. Then the solver would set `x^+ = 10` and `x^- = 0` to obtain

```
 x  = x^+ - x^- = 10
|x| = x^+ + x^- = 10.
```

And if `x = -10` in the optimal solution, then `x^+ = 0`, `x^- = 10`, and

```
 x  = x^+ - x^- = -10
|x| = x^+ + x^- =  10.
```

(The solver *won't* choose, say, `x^+ = 50` and `x^- = 40` to get `x = 10` because the simplex method always chooses extreme-point solutions.)

If you do this trick separately with each of the three `abs`'s in your model, it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Implementation is still a bit fuzzy to me but I should figure it out. If you have any code examples from where you have implemented this, that would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't -- I'm not an R user. Good luck!